# Let $E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y=x^2 \}$. Show that $(E,d_E)$ is a complete metric space.

Tags: general-topology, complete-spaces

> Let $E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y=x^2 \}$. Show that $(E,d_E)$ is a complete metric space. Here $d_E$ is just the restriction of $d_2$ to $E$.

I'm trying to show this using the preimage definition. I have that $$E=\{(x,y)\mid f(x,y)=0\}$$ where $f(x,y)=y-x^2$. Note that $f$ is continous so if $E$ is the preimage of a closed set then $E$ is closed and since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is complete and $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ this would imply that $E$ is also complete. I'm not sure I entirely understand the concept of preimage. It's quite clear that it's just the set of elements that map to the image of $f$, but how do I find it? I'm tempted so say that $$f^{-1}(\{0\}) = E$$ but this would mean that only $0$ gets mapped to $0$ which isn't true since if $x=y=1$ then $f(x,y)=0$ so the preimage would be $f^{-1}(\{0,1\})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given any function $g:X\to Y$ and $A\subseteq Y$ we have that

$$g^{-1}(A)=\{x\in X\ |\ g(x)\in A\}$$

This is simply the definition.

And so in your case $f^{-1}(\{0\})=E$ pretty much by the definition.

> but this would mean that only 0 gets mapped to 0

That doesn't even make sense, since $0\not\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f^{-1}(\{0\})\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$. Note that $(x,y)\in f^{-1}(\{0\})$ means that $f(x,y)=0$. Its equivalent.

> if $x=y=1$ then $f(x,y)=0$

Yes, and thus for $x=y=1$ we have that $(x,y)=(1,1)$ is an element of $f^{-1}(\{0\})$. And at the same time an element of $E$.

Comment: By $0$ I meant $(0,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. And how is $(x,y)=(1,1)$ an element of $f^{-1}(\{0\})$? Shouldn't $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ be just the singleton $0$ and since the singleton is closed $E$ is also?

Comment: Why would $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ be a singleton? That wouldn't even lead you to a solution since $E$ is not a singleton. Again: $(1,1)$ is an element of $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ because $f(1,1)=0$. That's the definition. Another example, say $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then what is $f^{-1}(\{0\})$? It is a singleton $\{0\}$. But what is $f^{-1}(\{r\})$ for any positive $r$? It is the circle of radius $r$. Because that's the solution to the equation $f(x,y)=r$.

Comment: Perhaps the "$f^{-1}$" notation confuses you. It doesn't mean "inverse function", your $f$ is not invertible. It means "preimage" as defined at the begining of my answer. Another simple example. Consider $f:\{1,2,3\}\to\{0\}$ given by (obviously) $f(x)=0$. Then $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\{1,2,3\}$. Sorry, but I don't think I can explain this better.

Comment: I know it means the preimage, but I think I have a hard time understanding why it is closed in this particular case.

Comment: @DanielLi preimages of closed sets are closed by continuity. You've said it yourself in the question. And the singleton $\{0\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is closed. And thus so is $f^{-1}(\{0\})$.

Answer (score 1):

We define $F(x,y)=x^2-y$. So $F^{-1}(\{0\})=\{(x,y):x^2=y\}=E$, and since $F$ is continuous as you mentioned, and ${0}$ is closed in $\Bbb{R}$ we get that $E$ is closed in $\Bbb{R^2}$ (as the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function). So $E\subseteq\Bbb{R^2}$ is a closed subset in a complete metric space and therefore $(E,d_E)$ is complete.

Answer (score 0):

About your concern regarding the preimage notation:
$$E = f^{-1}(\{0\})$$
is really just another way of writing the definition of $E$:
$$(x,y) \in f^{-1}(\{0\}) \iff f(x,y)\in \{0\} \iff f(x,y) = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

That's true that $f$ is continuous, and $E = f^{-1}(0)$, and since point zero is closed in $\mathbb R$ then by continuity of $f$ set $E$ is closed.You misunderstand the symbol $f^{-1}$, it's not and inverse map, we define the preimage of set $X \subset \mathbb R$ the same way$$f^{-1}(X) = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb R | f(x,y) \in X\}$$